# Android ADB to test SQLite schema updates

Tags: android, adb

[UPDATE: SOLUTION = Fixed onUpgrade() code which allowed successful testing of database schema changes using Debugger instead of packaging multiple apks]

I am attempting to test 2 apks to insure the database updates will occur when my app update is deployed to Market.

Test1.apk: contains sqlite schema_version = 1
Test2.apk: contains sqlite schema_version = 2

Both apks are digitally signed with the same key, using adb I'm able to install Test1.apk.  When I attempt to install Test2.apk, I receive:

Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS]

How do I test my new schema changes?  If the answer is from the Debugger, then when onUpgrade() is called, my databases is Always LOCKED.

```
//////////////// This Code Fixed The onUpgrade() Issue /////////////////////

@Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
            //TODO: Write DB Update logic.

            SQLiteDatabase upgradeDB = null;

            if (newVersion > oldVersion){           
                Log.e(TAG, "NEWER VERSION DETECTED, DATABASE UPGRADE REQUIRED!");               

                InputStream inputStream = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dbscript_v2_0_0_0); 
                BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1016688); //1016688 max 
                String buffer;
                try {

                    db.beginTransaction();

                    //openDataBase();
                    while ((buffer = br2.readLine()) != null) 
                    { 
                            String[] execSql = buffer.split("\n");  
                            execMultipleSQL(db, execSql);

                    } 
                    db.setTransactionSuccessful();      

                    Log.d(TAG, "onCreated sql: CREATED TABLES and INSERTED RECORDS");
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    db.endTransaction();
                    //db.close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "NO DATABASE UPGRADE DETECTED"); 
            }
        }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

```
        @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
                    //TODO: Write DB Update logic.

                    SQLiteDatabase upgradeDB = null;

                    if (newVersion > oldVersion){           
                        Log.e(TAG, "NEWER VERSION DETECTED, DATABASE UPGRADE REQUIRED!");               

                        InputStream inputStream = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.dbscript_v2_0_0_0); 
                        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream), 1016688); //1016688 max 
                        String buffer;
                        try {

                            String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null);
                            myDataBase.beginTransaction();

                            //openDataBase();
                            while ((buffer = br2.readLine()) != null) 
                            { 
                                    String[] execSql = buffer.split("\n");  
                                    execMultipleSQL(myDataBase, execSql);

                            } 
                            myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();      
                                //close();                  
                                Log.d(TAG, "onCreated sql: CREATED TABLES and INSERTED RECORDS");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            Log.e("Error creating tables and debug data", e.toString());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            myDataBase.endTransaction();
                            myDataBase.close();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.e(TAG, "NO DATABASE UPGRADE DETECTED"); 
                    }
                }


     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

                try
                {   
                    /* When the database is 1st installed on the device, this helper class creates a blank database using getWritableDatabase().
                     * The actual database is then populated using the SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(PATH, null, Open_ReadWrite) to exec the sql.
                     * 
                     * PROBLEM - SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() Does not call onUpgrade() so we're 
                     * unable to update the database for future versions
                     * 
                     * SOLUTION - Check to see if the dbExists, if not use SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase() 
                     * because it will create the DB from scripts, we don't care about onUpgrade();
                     * If the db does exist, call getWritableDatabase() to invoke onUpgrade checks for 
                     * future releases where the SCHEMA_VERSION is greater than the current db SCHEMA_VERSION
                     */
                    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
                    if(!dbExist){

                        /* Calls: DOES NOT call onUpgrade()
                         * Errors if db exists and there are db changes (New Columns/Tables), so use the below getWritableDatabase() instead                     */
                        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        /* Calls: onUpgrade()
                         * Errors if db does not exist, so use the above instead                     */
                        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();                    
                    }               

                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error SQLiteFactoryAdapter openDataBase " + e.toString());
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you opening the database?

It looks like you are extending SQLiteOpenHelper. The constructor has a parameter *version*, which represents the version of the schema. Why don't you just change this param in your test to test your onUpgrade() method

Side note: The reason you are getting the error message is because you are trying to deploy the same package again. You need to uninstall it before deploying it again. You can do this with the command `adb uninstall packagename.apk`.

Comment: Scroll down on my questions, I added the openDataBase() command used. - thnx

Comment: I have done that already.  When the Debugger gets to "myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME, null);" I receive a Database LOCKED error.

Comment: how come you are using a open helper to create the initial database, and not subsequently using the open helper from that stage?

Comment: I am aware of adb uninstall, but if I used it onUpgrade() is never called.

Comment: thats because you dont use the SQLiteOpenHelper if the database already exists. as your comments in the code rightfully states, onUpgrade will only be called if you use getWriteableDatabase() or getReadableDatabase().

Comment: taking a existing database, and changing it when the schema version is incremented is a update. For that to happen, a database needs to already exist, and since you only call getWriteableDatabase() if no database exists, the onUpgrade will never happen.

Comment: Thanks!  I overlooked your question as to why I'm not using the helper onUpgrade().  Good catch, that was my problem, instead of using myDataBase and trying to open it, I needed to use db provided with the onUpgrade() arguments " public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)"